# Corrupted images when using ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB (support lib) for NV21 to Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, renderscript, yuv

I am having issues when using ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB from the support library to convert images from NV21 format to Bitmaps (ARGB_8888). The code below can illustrate the problem.

Suppose I have the following 50x50 image (the one below is a screenshot from device, not actually 50x50):

[image]

Then if I convert said image to a Bitmap through the `YuvImage#compressToJpeg` + `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray`:

```
YuvImage yuvImage = new YuvImage(example, android.graphics.ImageFormat.NV21, width, height, null);
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
yuvImage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 100, os);
byte[] jpegByteArray = os.toByteArray();
return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jpegByteArray, 0, jpegByteArray.length);
```

I get the expected image. But if I convert it through ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB as following:

```
RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(context);

Type.Builder tb = new Type.Builder(rs, Element.createPixel(rs,
        Element.DataType.UNSIGNED_8, Element.DataKind.PIXEL_YUV));
tb.setX(width);
tb.setY(height);
tb.setYuvFormat(android.graphics.ImageFormat.NV21);
Allocation yuvAllocation = Allocation.createTyped(rs, tb.create(), Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
yuvAllocation.copyFrom(example);

Type rgbType = Type.createXY(rs, Element.RGBA_8888(rs), width, height);
Allocation rgbAllocation = Allocation.createTyped(rs, rgbType);

ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB yuvToRgbScript = ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB.create(rs, Element.RGBA_8888(rs));
yuvToRgbScript.setInput(yuvAllocation);
yuvToRgbScript.forEach(rgbAllocation);

Bitmap convertedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
rgbAllocation.copyTo(convertedBitmap);
```

I get the following corrupted image:

[image]

I have noticed that this happens with images of square sizes and never with powers of 2 (e.g. 64x64, 128x128, etc). Had I not tried square sizes I would not have noticed the problem, as some picture sizes such as 2592x1728 works ok. What am I missing?

Update: putting the code that generated the original image as requested:

```
int width = 50;
int height = 50;
int size = width * height;

byte[] example = new byte[size + size / 2];
for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        example[y * width + x] = (byte) ((x*y / (float)size) * 255);
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < size / 2; i++) {
    example[size + i] = (byte) (127);
}
```

Comment: Can you post an input file, which could be used to test your code? It is a bit difficult to reproduce the error, otherwise. :)

Comment: @cmaster11 I did better than that, I just added the code that generated the input image at the end of the question :)

Comment: Note that `ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB` is wrong for camera preview frames, because it assumes the *video* [BT.610](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr#ITU-R_BT.601_conversion) color space (where **Y** is in range `[16…235]`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code behaves in the wrong way:

```
Type.Builder tb = new Type.Builder(rs, Element.createPixel(rs,
                    Element.DataType.UNSIGNED_8, Element.DataKind.PIXEL_YUV));
tb.setX(width);
tb.setY(height);
tb.setYuvFormat(android.graphics.ImageFormat.NV21);
yuvAllocation = Allocation.createTyped(rs, tb.create(), Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
```

If you replace it using a "raw" way of creating an allocation, the conversion will work:

```
int expectedBytes = width * height *
                ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel(ImageFormat.NV21) / 8;

Type.Builder yuvTypeBuilder = new Type.Builder(rs, Element.U8(rs))
                                                   .setX(expectedBytes);
Type yuvType = yuvTypeBuilder.create();
yuvAllocation = Allocation.createTyped(rs, yuvType, Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
```

It seems that, if you use the `PIXEL_YUV` definition, there is a size problem on non-multiple-of-16 dimensions. Still investigating on it.

Comment: as far as I understand, any even (as in odd/even) resolution dimensions images are acceptable for NV21 (see http://i.stack.imgur.com/NqqJD.png for reference on the format. You'll see that even the example is 6x4 which is not divisible by 16. So it seems a 50x50 image NV21-valid, but I might be doing something wrong or there is a bug in the ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRgb.

Comment: That image refers NOT to NV21, it was just an example to show you what is the memory allocation of a planar YUV system.

Comment: What is wrong about it? I have used that format reference on several occasions for direct byte manipulation on the format.

Comment: Let me look up the conversion process :)

Comment: Gotcha :) Changed my answer

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the update :)  so I just tried your code and it gives me the result in the end of the (now twice edited :) ) question. Maybe I missed something important in the code, like setYuvFormat(ImageFormat.NV21), but if I do that it crashes.

Comment: Now, that is curious because we have the same code! Can you share your new activity code, on http://pastebin.com/ ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121358/discussion-between-cmaster11-and-silvaren).

Comment: Sure @cmaster11. I'm there to provide the details.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO the best way to convert NV21 (or NV12) to ARGB on Android is to use native (C++) LibYUV library
https://chromium.googlesource.com/libyuv/libyuv/

The main advantage on ARM v7 (and newest v8) based Android Devices is NEON optimization which makes conversion extremely fast.

You can make own build of LibYUV ([Build Instruction](http://mohdazharinamdar.blogspot.com.by/2015/05/building-libyuv-shared-library-for.html)) or use any prebuild from github: https://github.com/search?q=libyuv+Android